# Add inline image in java mail sender

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail

In my project when i send mail to gmail or yahoo mail then my image bind as inline image to the body part. But when i open the same mail in outlook then it show that image as attachement and show blank space in body part.

```
MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {             
    @Override
    public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
        MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage,true);
        messageHelper.setTo("abc@xyz.com");
        messageHelper.setFrom("info@abc.com");
        messageHelper.setSubject("Test");   
        messageHelper.setText(text, true);
        FileSystemResource res = new FileSystemResource(new File(message_image_path));
        messageHelper.addInline("identifier1234", res);
    }
};
```

where *message_image_path* is path of my image and *text* is my html message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm...   I didn't actually see a question in there, but I'm assuming you're asking why is it different.  The reason it's different is because they're different programs written by different people.  There's nothing that **requires** an email message to be displayed in any specific way.  The information about attachments vs. inline is just hints to the mail reader.  Some mail readers ignore those hints.  There's not much you can do about that.

If you're trying to get a specific mail reader to display a message in a specific way, your best bet is to compose such a message in that mail reader, then look at the structure of the message you composed and duplicate that with JavaMail.  Of course, that might not mean the message will display as expected in some other mail reader.

Your best bet is to keep it simple.  Simple html, referencing images included with the message (a multipart/related message), may be the best way to accomplish what you want.